# Laravel event RevokeOldToken error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck with a problem: I created an event according to the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#events).

I created the files with `php artisan event:generate`

This command created two files:

- `Listeners/RevokeOldToken.php`
- `Listeners/PruneOldTokens.php`

After that when I hit the API, it returns this error:

> Argument 1 passed to `App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens::handle()` must be an instance of `App\Events\Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated`, instance of `Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated` given

What i am doing wrong? How can I create the instance said by the error?

Comment: Is there anything I can add to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46472602/1494454) that wasn't addressed from the bounty tender? Please let me know.

Comment: sorry, forgot about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need import that two class in listener.

```
use Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated;
use Laravel\Passport\Events\RefreshTokenCreated;
```

I think you didn't import them, so laravel think your listener is expecting that two wrong classes, `App\Events\Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated` and `App\Events\Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated`

Comment: you're right! that was the issue, i used php artisan to create the files, so he automatically import those two files with wrong paths.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Artisan generates an incorrect `use` path for the event classes in the listener files so you have to fix them, by removing the `App\Events` part from the front.

### Explanation

The Generating Events & Listeners subsection under the [documentation's Registering Events & Listeners section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#registering-events-and-listeners) mentions that the event and listener classes are generated based on the `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php` class' `listen` attribute.

This is a nice feature, but there is a little problem with it: **if the array's keys** (the event file paths) **in the `$listen` attribute reference an event from the `vendor` folder** (`Laravel\Passport\Events` in this case) then in the generated listener file, **the imported event's path will be prefixed with `App\Events\`**. This is the thing that you have to remove.

Because of this, the `use` **path now references a non existing class that doesn't raise an error** like "using non existing class", so when the code gets executed and the event is fired, then thanks to the mappings in the `EventServiceProvider.php` file, the proper event listener will be found for the event, but **when the listener's `handle` method is called with the event, it will raise a type error** (which is a PHP thing), **because** the argument's **type hinting references a different** (non existing) **class**.

### Catching the bug in action

If we dig deep into the framework, we can find the [`Illuminate/Foundation/Console/EventGenerateCommand.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/EventGenerateCommand.php) class the gets executed when you call `php artisan event:generate`. You can see that it [parses the `EventServiceProvider` class' `listen` attribute](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/EventGenerateCommand.php#L32-L36) then starts to generate [event](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/EventGenerateCommand.php#L54) and [listener](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/EventGenerateCommand.php#L56) files.

The listener generation will happen in the [`Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ListenerMakeCommand.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ListenerMakeCommand.php) file, that will create the generated file [based on](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ListenerMakeCommand.php#L72) the stub found in [`Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/listener.stub`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/listener.stub).

The dummy import path [will be replaced in the `buildClass` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ListenerMakeCommand.php#L54). The [new path has been calculated](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ListenerMakeCommand.php#L42-L48) just before the replace took place and that is where the error happens:

```php
if (! Str::startsWith($event, [
    $this->laravel->getNamespace(),
    'Illuminate',
    '\\',
])) {
    $event = $this->laravel->getNamespace().'Events\\'.$event;
}
```

In our case `$event` will start with `Laravel\Passport\Events` and not with `App\`, `Illuminate` or `\` so the path will be prefixed with `App\Events\`. That is the thing you should remove in the generated files.

I hope this is official enough.